# facebook messenger api “(#100) No matching user found”

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

im using facebook sdk and i keep getting an error message “(#100) No matching user found” and i followed the instruction on facebook documentation but i keep getting this message i already check the user id who i want to send it to also i used already an static id for this to check if im getting the wrong id from senders conversation api. i don't know if this is a bug or am i doing it wrong, i already added messenger product on my app

```
FB.api('/'+id+'/conversations?access_token=' + token + '&fields=senders','GET',function(conversations){
                FB.api('/'+id+'/messages?access_token=' + token ,'POST',{
                    'recipient' : {'id' : conversations.data[0].senders.data[0].name},
                    'message' : {'text' :'hello ' + conversations.data[0].senders.data[0].name},
                },function(messages){
                    console.log(messages);
                });
            });
            });
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? do you want to reply to a user message on a page?

Comment: im am trying to send a message to all user who message my page and i the conversation api will do the work and message them all

Comment: to all of them at once? sounds spammy...

Comment: where you able to fix this? I'm making a kinda chatbox but the sender_id I get from the webhook POST is incorrect.

Comment: @fmtoffolo did you found solution for sender_id being incorrect in webhook?